# about save Activity state

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-progressbar

```
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    Init();
    backthread tr=new backthread();
    tr.execute(0,0,0);
}
```

backthread is a class implements AsyncTask 
when the program runing in MainActivity ,the progressbar's value will increase from 0 to 100 (change its value in backthread),but when i go into other activity and turn back ,the progressbar will restart from 0 to 100 , i want progressbar's value continue increase when i go into other activity and turn back; what should i do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can keep a int variable in currentUptae in backthread class and in onProgressUpdaete update this variable as well.

create the getter and setter for and just upate the progress bar by this currentUptae variable in OnRestart or onStart ........

Answer (score 0):

In doInBackground() you should use publishProgress(progress++) to update progress result and

```
   @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
      super.onProgressUpdate(values);
      tvInfo.setText("Downloaded " + values[0] + " files"); // progress bar 
    }
```

Comment: thanks.but if the AnsycTask is not a class include in MainActivity i don't know how to use the method.